# How to change date format value in form react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I have some problem when I want to get the date from JSON that output in format `31-10-2019 07:00:00`, I want to change that format to **YYYY-MM-DD**, but at the moment, the field still displays `dd/mm/yyyy`, for more detail look at my code :

```
<FormGroup>
    <Label for="expiredDate">Expired Date</Label>
    <Input
        type="date"
        name="expiredDate"
        onChange = {this.handleForm}
        value = {moment(new Date(expiredDate)).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
        placeholder="date placeholder"
        min = {moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")}/>
</FormGroup>
```

[IN User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwy7g.png)

Fixed it with 
`moment(expiredDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Comment: so what should i do if i want to display in UI with format "DD/MM/YYYY" ?

Comment: you can write a function to manipulate it.

Comment: what function ?

Comment: what is the date you receiving?

Comment: 25-01-2021 07:00:00 from server json

Comment: i think he just want the dates to show and not the time!

Comment: so how to display that bro without changin the format? it stlll DD/MM/YYYY in UI

Comment: you're the one who understand me @Udit

Comment: you can do that by using `new Date().toLocaleDateString()`

Comment: already try it . still display dd/mm/yyyy on UI . new Date(expiredDate).toLocaleDateString() ?

Comment: yes! you won't need moment()

Comment: or can you share a CodeSandbox?

Comment: it result invalid date, i already try to console.log .

Comment: @AlexsandroSiregar check i posted example, if it won't help please share your snippet and data that you are getting.

Comment: @VahidAkhtar Thanks, but where i put my value expiredDate?

Comment: @AlexsandroSiregar the dateTime you are getting from response is causing the issue

Comment: ha? really ? i dont think so, because

```var date = "14-06-2019 07:00:00"
var dateTime = new Date(date).toTimeString;
dateTime = moment(dateTime).format("DD/MM/YYYY");

console.log(dateTime)
```

i use that, still in valid Date

Comment: `"14-06-2019 07:00:00" ` is coming out to be an invalid date if we try to convert it into your desired format, that's because it is not the supported format

Comment: @Udit i already fixed it broo

become ```moment(expiredDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss').format('YYYY-MM-DD')```

Comment: @AlexsandroSiregar perfect, you can share the answer, in the answer section for anyone else to see